# No command output error in eclipse when running HelloAndroid program

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am new to Android programming.
Received this error when i try to run my Hello Android program.
The emulator doesn't show the "Hello Android" after that.

error log:

```
eclipse.buildId=M20100909-0800
java.version=1.6.0_23
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_MY
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86


Error
Sun Dec 19 19:11:04 SGT 2010
No command output when running: 'am start -n com.example.helloandroid/com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER' on device emulator-5554

com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException
at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:408)
at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:276)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.ActivityLaunchAction.doLaunchAction(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.launchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.simpleLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.access$3(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController$3.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: you should show us some of your code. If you update your question to include your _AndroidManifest.xml_ file, this might give us the necessary info to tell you what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

That an error in your eclipse configuration.

Check that you have configure it correctly.